# Json Array object access

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js, vuejs2

I want some help in getting data form json array file is in the link

```
  Html
  <div>
    <div v-for="data in myJson.id " >{{ data }}</div>
  </div>
      js
    import json from '.././json/data.json'
      export default {
    components: {
      MainLayout,
    },
  data: function(){
        return {
          myJson:json
        }
      },
  method:{
    getjson:function(){
      this.json = JSON.parse(myJson);
    }
  }
  }
```

i want to access only the data with some specific id and i cannot access it using the syntax i am using

edit 
[image: this is i am getting in result]
[Json file](https://jsonblob.com/6ee20119-7cfb-11e7-9e0d-1778d5c41933)

Comment: There's no such a thing as "_json array_". You either have a JSON datastring or JS array. What the syntax you've tried looks like?

Comment: You are just parsing your json response, where are you trying to access?

Comment: sorry that parse function is not wokring

Comment: You don't have an id property on this json, therefore can't access it. Do you want to check for the name property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you do not even need `JSON.parse`. It seems to work without it... Put your JSON file in the same directory as your component and try this:

```
import data from './data.json'

export default {
  created () {
    for (const item of data[0]['file']) {
      console.log(`
        Name: ${item.name}
        Type: ${item.type}
        Size: ${item.filesize}
        Dimensions: ${item.dimension[0].width}x${item.dimension[0].height}
      `)
    }
  }
}
```

You should see information from your JSON file in your console when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
  import MainLayout from '../layouts/Main.vue'
  import json from '.././json/data.json'

  export default {
    components: {
      MainLayout,
    },
  data: function(){
    return {
     myJson: json[0].file
    }
  },
  method:{

    }
  }
</script>   

 html
  <div v-for="data in myJson">
    {{ data.name }}
    {{ data.filesize}}
    {{ data.dimension[0].width}}x{{data.dimension[0].height}}
  </div>
```

using the above code i utilized and used to implemented according to my needs and it worked